# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url') when trying to paginate

Tags: typescript, graphql, pagination, lazy-loading, astrojs

I'm following along with this pagination and lazy loading tutorial: https://hygraph.com/blog/lazy-load-content-astro-hygraph-pagination

I played around in Hygraphs's API playground and swapped 'post' with 'product' where needed to make it fit my data, also I'm sorting by published, not created At.

Here is my astro.index page:

```
---
import Card from "../components/Card.astro";
import BaseLayout from "../layouts/BaseLayout.astro";

const pageTitle = "My Page Title";

const pageSize = 3;

const response = await fetch(import.meta.env.PUBLIC_HYGRAPH_ENDPOINT, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `query MyQuery($size: Int) {
          pages:productsConnection(first: $size, orderBy: publishedAt_DESC) {
            products:edges {
              node {
                id
                title
                publishedAt
                slug
                previewImage {
                  id
                  url
                }
              }
            }
            pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
              hasPreviousPage
            }
          }
        }
        `,
    variables: { size: pageSize },
  }),
});

const data = await response.json();
const { pages } = data.data;
---

<BaseLayout pageTitle={pageTitle}>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 justify-center">
    {
      pages.products.map((product) => {
        return <Card title={product.title} image={product.previewImage.url} />;
      })
    }
  </div>
</BaseLayout>
```

And for refference here is the Card component I'm using:

```
---
const { title, image } = Astro.props;
const maxTitleLength = 32;`your text`
const shortTitle =
  title.length > maxTitleLength
    ? `${title.substring(0, maxTitleLength)}...`
    : title;
---

<div class="card sm:w-full lg:w-96 bg-primary">
  <figure>
    <img class="object-cover h-64 w-full" src={image} alt={title} />
  </figure>
  <div class="card-body overflow-hidden">
    <h2 class="card-title">{shortTitle}</h2>
    <div class="card-actions justify-center">
      <button class="btn btn-glass">More Details</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wanted 3 items to load on the page so that I can implement a 'load more' button but it gives me the TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Comment: Look at the data you are getting back. Is it possible that `product.previewImage` is undefined?

Comment: I tried console logging 'pages.products' and I get an array of nodes back containing all the query items but previewImage has the value of [Object]. Should I somehow destructure that aswell to get to use the 'url' property? EDIT: here is an example of one of the nodes I get back: ` [ {
    node: {
      id: 'cld8rlyxt512h0amnemc082ma',
      title: 'Cotton Road Bags  CR888',
      publishedAt: '2023-01-30T06:44:36.870342+00:00',
      slug: 'cotton-road-bags-cr888',
      previewImage: [Object]
    }
  },] `

Comment: Try `product.previewImage?.url` and see what happens. That should at least mask the error then you can see which image might be missing a url.

Comment: Hmmm did as suggested and now a new error seems to be pointing at the Card component: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` It seems to be pointing at where I defined the source and alt attributes. Will try to mess around there and see if I can get it to read in the `url` property I need

Comment: It seems to me I cannot wrap my head around this, I might try a few different methods of pagination,  I may end up doing it with react inside Astro as I have been told it integrates well and there is a `react-paginate` package that handles a lot of the logic. Thanks for taking the time to help, I will ponder this problem.

Comment: Are you sure this is a code problem and not a data problem? Can you run the GraphQL query outside of your code (for example in GraphiQL) and verify that you're getting what you expect?

Comment: I'm away from the keyboard at the moment(South Africa has load-shedding so no power) but I think that may be the case, I used a different query earlier today to load every product and its preview image and it loaded it into cards with no problem. I changed the query to follow the tutorial but I suspect that could be incompatible with my current data. I'm going to use Astro's built-in pagination I just found out about alongside the query that I made earlier that worked. I'm hopeful that it may do the trick, will update tommorow if it works out.